# Latex and Memoir class, guillemot left/right

Tags: latex, memoir

I am using memoir class with latex, and I need the two characters:

"«", and "»".

I found the following commands:

`\guillemotright` and `\guillemotleft`, but they look *very* ugly. Is there something wrong in what I am doing? Latex source:

http://pastebin.com/1w0J6jbN

Result:
[image]

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

—Albé

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong in what you are doing, but you are perhaps being a bit critical of the appearance of the guillemots.  Ugliness, after all, is in the eye of the beholder.  You might have a more pleasing result if you choose a different font (family or set) for your document,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are these chractrers in the russian font

```
{
\font\larm = larm1000
\larm
\char 190 \char 191
}
```

[alt text http://img293.imageshack.us/img293/2119/overbrace1.png](http://img293.imageshack.us/img293/2119/overbrace1.png)

Answer (score 2):

i recommend to

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and even

```
\usepackage{aeguill}
```

from the french language pack. this way you can simply write your guillemets and you dont have to use `\guillemotleft` and `\guillemotright`